# SQL Compound Growth Calculation based on previous rows (varying rate)

Tags: sql, presto

Given a column for 'Growth Factors' and a starting value I need to compute future values. For example, if a starting value of 1 is provided then the computed 'Value' column would be as shown below. Thus, Value(t2) = Value(t1) x Growth_Factor(t2). Base condition is Value(t1) = Starting_Value x Growth_Factor(t1). Example shown below.
**How do I compute this in SQL (or Presto) where the computed value is dependent on previous computed values?**

| Growth Factor | Value | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.2 | 1.2 | 1 |
| 1.1 | 1.32 | 2 |
| 1.5 | 1.98 | 3 |
| 1.7 | 3.366 | 4 |

Comment: Sorry, missed the time column earlier. Updated the table.

Comment: You could use a recursive CTE for this, but unfortunately prestodb does not yet implement them.

Answer (score 1):

You could sum the logarithms and invert when finished. This will work other than some possibility of small floating point error. But you're also going to introduce error once you multiply more than a few numbers with doubling decimal places at every iteration.

```
exp(
    sum(ln(growth)) over (order by time)
)
```

Comment: That's pretty smart. Not sure if presto will keep the correct precision, though, but this should work.